# Custom Font Issue In Android

Tags: android

I am trying to use custom font in android. I have written java code as given below.

```
TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.customfont);
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Molot.otf");
txt.setTypeface(font);
```

where I have stored the custom font in "./assets/fonts/" folder.

But, I am getting nullpointerexception on the 3rd line.

Can anybody give me the solution for this issue? Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Android supports `only TTF` font type `not OTF`. Check this link

["RuntimeException: native typeface cannot be made" when loading font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3023960/crash-when-loading-font)

Comment: Thanks a Lot! But I tried even using .ttf, it doesn't work yet...and still throws the same exception

Comment: Please note that the Font name you are entering is case sensitive. If you are still stuck up i probably think it should be a issue with the Font file you are using. Try downloading a different font TTF file and loading it.After a quick googling i found this website which can convert OTF to TTF. May be you can give a try http://onlinefontconverter.com/

Comment: You can also check this post which has a sample project associated with it... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203694

Comment: Did you download the sample project available with the above link and try running it?..it should work http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Fonts/FontSampler/

Answer (score 1):

Android supports OTF as well. Your font may be corrupt.

Download delicious font from www.exljbris.com/delicious.html. It is an otf font and it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
    `Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "/fonts/Molot.otf");`