# App runs fine on emulator but crashes on device

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have an application of which i have two codes, one the latest one and the other is old one. i am merging my latest code with old one using DiffMerge utility. When I run the app on emulator after merging it runs fine but crashes on the device at the very first activity. the LogCat shows me the following:

I am Just showing the exception that is thrown when i run the app from Eclipse on my device.

06-29 10:34:09.554: WARN/System.err(1296): java.lang.RuntimeException: native typeface cannot be made

any help please.

Comment: Have you checked previous same kind of posts over here? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3023960/crash-when-loading-font) also check [link_1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717054/custom-fonts-in-android)

Comment: Yes, I have, but couldn't find an appropriate answer.

Comment: Finally, i have got an answer myself, the solution is name of font file i mean .ttf file must be same in both the codes, even case must be same. It has worked me after a lot of research on this small but really irritating problem, hope this works for others as well.

Comment: @ Balaji, it was so nice of you, but that wasn't the right solution in my case. but thanks anyway.

Comment: @Usama answer your own question and mark it as answered :-)

Comment: @Blundell...I cannot mark my own question as answered..or can i..????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, i have got an answer myself, the solution is name of font file i mean .ttf file must be same in both the codes, even case must be same. It has worked me after a lot of research on this small but really irritating problem, hope this works for others as well:-)