# How to add alternative font to Button text in Android?

Tags: java, android, button, custom-font

I am trying to use the Calibri font on a button in one of my Android applications, and after searching around for a bit i found out how to make your own Typeface. But when i try to set the typeface on the button it doesn't give me an error, but the application won't launch.
  Does anyone know how to fix that?

```
final Button bt4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt4);
final Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"CALIBRI.ttf");
bt4.setTypeface(font);
```

this is pretty much all the code i have used to this point.

and the log cat information

```
08-29 13:31:20.593: E/global(1143): Deprecated Thread methods are not supported.
08-29 13:31:20.593: E/global(1143): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
08-29 13:31:20.593: E/global(1143):     at java.lang.VMThread.stop(VMThread.java:85)
08-29 13:31:20.593: E/global(1143):     at java.lang.Thread.stop(Thread.java:1280)
08-29 13:31:20.593: E/global(1143):     at java.lang.Thread.stop(Thread.java:1247)
08-29 13:31:20.593: E/global(1143):     at com.github.TheCad.nijmegen1.SplashScreen$1.run(SplashScreen.java:33)
08-29 13:31:21.553: D/AndroidRuntime(1143): Shutting down VM
08-29 13:31:21.553: W/dalvikvm(1143): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
08-29 13:31:21.583: E/AndroidRuntime(1143): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-29 13:31:21.583: E/AndroidRuntime(1143): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.github.TheCad.nijmegen1/com.github.TheCad.nijmegen1.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: native typeface cannot be made
08-29 13:31:21.583: E/AndroidRuntime(1143):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
08-29 13:31:21.583: E/AndroidRuntime(1143):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
08-29 13:31:21.583: E/AndroidRuntime(1143):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
08-29 13:31:21.583: E/AndroidRuntime(1143):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
08-29 13:31:21.583: E/AndroidRuntime(1143):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-29 13:31:21.583: E/AndroidRuntime(1143):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-29 13:31:21.583: E/AndroidRuntime(1143):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
08-29 13:31:21.583: E/AndroidRuntime(1143):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-29 13:31:21.583: E/AndroidRuntime(1143):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-29 13:31:21.583: E/AndroidRuntime(1143):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
08-29 13:31:21.583: E/AndroidRuntime(1143):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
08-29 13:31:21.583: E/AndroidRuntime(1143):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-29 13:31:21.583: E/AndroidRuntime(1143): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: native typeface cannot be made
08-29 13:31:21.583: E/AndroidRuntime(1143):     at android.graphics.Typeface.<init>(Typeface.java:147)
08-29 13:31:21.583: E/AndroidRuntime(1143):     at android.graphics.Typeface.createFromAsset(Typeface.java:121)
08-29 13:31:21.583: E/AndroidRuntime(1143):     at com.github.TheCad.nijmegen1.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25)
08-29 13:31:21.583: E/AndroidRuntime(1143):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
08-29 13:31:21.583: E/AndroidRuntime(1143):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
08-29 13:31:21.583: E/AndroidRuntime(1143):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Without looking into your code, nobody can suggest or help you out.

Comment: and relevant logcat information.

Comment: did you update your activity in `AndroidManifest.xml` ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by updating?

Comment: did you add your activity to the AndroidManifest.xml ?

Comment: O yes it is added there.

Comment: <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

Comment: Might want to keep in mind the Calibri font included with Windows isn't licensed for redistribution.

Comment: see this SO question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3023960/crash-when-loading-font

Comment: Also, the name for the font that you pass into the `createFromAsset()` method is case-sensitive, so make sure that your font is in the root `assets/` folder, and is named `CALIBRI.ttf` and not `Calibri.ttf` or `calibri.ttf`.

Comment: that for one i did know, and it is indeed in all caps

Comment: I don't think that the errors caused by using `Typeface `. Did you use Thread? Please post the whole code of `MainActivity`.

Comment: My internet did just die on my so i will post the code when i get it back to work

Answer (score 1):

You have create TypeFace to do at RunTime.

Example:

```
Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.BUTTON_ID);
Typeface face=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/FONT_NAME.TTF");
btn.setTypeface(face);
```

**Update:**
You have error at 25th line of mainactivity.
Post that line.

Comment: That is the line `final Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"CALIBRI.ttf");`

Answer (score 0):

create a folder named "font" in the assets folder and store your font "calibri.ttf" in that folder, also try saving your font name in small letters and use this code,

```
Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.BUTTON_ID);
Typeface face= = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "font/calibri.ttf");
btn.setTypeface(face);
```